# javascript for mouse hover in c# selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I wanted to mouse hover on a menu which has many sub menu. In the websites where I researched they suggest below actions to use. But actions hovers over other menu there by hiding the actual element that has to be hovered.

```
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
Actions hoverclick = action.MoveToElement(HomePageMaps.MegaMenuDevelopAndGrowAsManager());
hoverclick.Build().Perform();
```

**Please suggest a java script for mouse hovering that can be used in selenium C# [Visual Studio IDE].**

As well I have tried the below java script for hovering but it doesn't hover instead it just brings the focus on the element.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor exe = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
exe.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');", xpath of the element to be hovered());
```

Comment: the following link will help you
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355515/how-to-do-a-mouse-over-using-selenium-webdriver-to-see-the-hidden-menu-without-p)

Comment: Do you have a URL where we can test on?

Comment: @Tinkle Can you consider to share the relevant HTML DOM along with your work? Thanks

Comment: No guys URL and DOM is confidential :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using JQuery,

```
IJavaScriptExecutor exe = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
exe.ExecuteScript($("Your Element Selector").hover(function(){$(this).css("background-color", "white"); },);
```

Your Element Selector - Give your Web Element which is to be hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and make use of the move to element action, this will simulate the action.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(elementId)));

Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply on my query. I tried the above piece of code but its not working. As I mentioned if i use actions it hovers other web element and hides the element which has to be hovered.