# How to mouse hover using java through selenium-webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

While trying to automate the portal http://demo.nopcommerce.com/, am not able to select mouse hover over "Electornics" menu and select "Camera & Photo" sub menu.
Used the below script for the same.

```
WebElement electronic_Pdts = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='title']//*[@title='Show products in category Electronics']"));
action.moveToElement(electronic_Pdts).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@src='http://demo.nopcommerce.com/images/thumbs/0000006_camera-photo_450.jpeg']")).click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386828/7429447) over ***Electornics*** menu and select ***Camera & Photo*** you can use the following code block :

```
driver.get("http://demo.nopcommerce.com/");
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement electronics = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li/a[@href='/electronics']")));
act.moveToElement(electronics).perform();
WebElement camera_n_photo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[@href='/electronics']//following::ul/li/a"));
camera_n_photo.click();
System.out.println("Camera & photo Clicked.");
```