# How to Mouse Hover over different images with dynamic xpaths through Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mousehover, webdriverwait

There are seven images. I want to do mouse hover on every image and and check AddToCart button is displayed or not. I have tried following code and it is not working.

Reference: http://automationpractice.com/index.php

```
public boolean checkMouseHoveronAllItems(WebDriver driver)
{
    String xpathOfItems="//[@id='homefeatured']/li['+index+']/div/div[1]/div/a[1]/img";                                                                        
    String xpathOfAddToCartButtons="//div[@class='button-container']/a[@title='Add to cart']";
    boolean res=false;
    for(int index=1;index<=countNoOfItems(driver);index++)
    {
        element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfItems));
        performMouseHover(element);
        System.out.println("Item By index"+element.getAttribute("alt"));
        element=element.findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfAddToCartButtons));
        if(element.isDisplayed())
        {
            res=true;               
            Log.info("Element is available");
        }
        else 
        {
            res=false;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Code always taking the fist element and printing the alt attribute text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261894/7429447) over all the *seven (7)* images and check if the element with text as **AddToCart** is displayed or not you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='homefeatured']"))));
List<WebElement> myProducts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@id='homefeatured']//div[@class='product-image-container']/a/img")));
for(WebElement product:myProducts)
{
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(product).build().perform();

    if(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@id='homefeatured']//div[@class='product-image-container']/a/img//following::a[@title='Add to cart']/span"))).isDisplayed())
        System.out.println("AddToCart button is displayed");
    else{
        System.out.println("AddToCart button is not displayed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this and let me know if it works.It worked for me.

```
List<WebElement> elmntimg=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@class='replace-2x img-responsive']"));
            boolean res=false;

            for(int ix=0;ix<elmntimg.size();ix++)
            {
             Actions action=new Actions(driver);
             action.moveToElement(elmntimg.get(ix)).build().perform();
             System.out.println("Item By index"+elmntimg.get(ix).getAttribute("alt"));
             WebElement elecart=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button-container']/a[@title='Add to cart']"));
             if(elecart.isDisplayed())
                 res=true;
                 System.out.println("Element is available");


            }
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. If i want to perform same operation to single element also this would work.

Comment: How do you avoid the rest of the elements that are found with the xPath of the list of images? Because in the page are displayed 7 elements, but if you paste the XPath in the Web console, it returns 14 elements. In code, it throws an error because the rest of the elements are not displayed.