# How to identify the text within the <a> using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, mousehover

This is the code of the demo store I want to test:

```
 <li class="level0 nav-2 parent">
      <a href="http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/men.html" 
               class="level0 has-children">Men</a> 
        <ul class="level0">
            <li class="level1 view-all">
               <a class="level1" href="http://demo- 
                         store.seleniumacademy.com/men.html">View All 
                         Men</a>
            </li>
               <li class="level1 nav-2-1 first"><a></a></li>
               <li class="level1 nav-2-2"><a href="http://demo- 
                          store.seleniumacademy.com/men/shirts.html" 
                          class="level1">text to get</a> 
               </li>
               <li class="level1 nav-2-3"><a></a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
```

I want to get text of those subcategories so I can later click on specific category by using text inside of a link element. My code is:

```
public Subcategory openSubcategory (String subcategoryName){

    List<WebElement> subcategories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.level1"));

    for (WebElement element: subcategories) {
        if (element.getText().equals(subcategoryName)){
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
    return new Subcategory(driver);
}
```

But it won't go inside loop, probably because `element.getText()` is empty.

Comment: Maybe you are missing some delay / wait here?

Comment: Try with https://api.jquery.com/text/ or https://api.jquery.com/html/ methods

Comment: I tried to add wait but implicit wait get crossed out. Maybe I put wait on a wrong place. Where shoud it be?

Comment: @StefanItic I meant to put a delay, not implicit wait. Put it before the line where you collecting the elements. I.e. before `List<WebElement> subcategories = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a.level1"));`

Comment: @Prophet Sorry but i'm newbie here, so I don't know how to add delay. I just know about implicit and explicit waits... Can you give me the code that I should implement inside, plese?

Comment: I mean something like `Thread.sleep(2000);` A simple, dummy pause.

Comment: In case this will help we will be able to do this with explicit wait as well

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: http://demo-store.seleniumacademy.com/ 
This is the store where I want to click on MEN -> SHIRTS, I tried everything and after 4 days I'm here, looking for help... Maybe you can find something inside code that i didn't see, that's why I pasted link to the store.

Comment: @StefanItic debug your code and try using other queries to see if those go through(eg. `".level1"`).

Comment: ((RemoteWebElement)element).id = Cannot find local variable 'element'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) with text as ***Shirts*** first you have to [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261894/7429447) the element with text as ***Men*** inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [visibilityOfElementLocated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
public Subcategory openSubcategory (String subcategoryName){

    WebElement menuMen = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'has-children') and text()='Men']")));
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(menuMen).build().perform();
    List<WebElement> subcategories = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'has-children') and text()='Men']//following::ul[1]//li/a"));
    for (WebElement element: subcategories) {
        if (element.getText().equals(subcategoryName)){
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
    return new Subcategory(driver);
}
```

Comment: OMG it's finally working!!!! Thank you sooo much!! Can you please explain to me how do you use xpath? I used it on a very simple way, but I don't understand everything you typed in xpath.

Comment: @StefanItic The element with text _**Men**_ has the _class_ _`level0 has-children`_ where as I considered only _`has-children`_ as I suspected _`level0`_ to be dynamic. Further the desired `<ul>` element in just the following element which have a descendant `li -> a`

Answer (score 1):

element.getText() can be empty.

Try:

```
element.getAttribute("value");
// or
element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Change your CSS to be:

```
"a[class*='level']";
// or
"a[]";
```

Debug the code and check if the element is not null

Comment: I tried both, not working

Comment: element.getAttribute("href")?

Comment: It might get href but i want text so I can call method and compare text inside link and text I typed.
I tried btw and it didn't click on link i want to.

Comment: Try to get only element with the tag A. Debug the code and tell me what is written inside element.getAttribute("href")

Comment: I don't know how to find what is written inside...

Comment: @StefanItic Debug you code, or just print the info to the console.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d54a4592f07c54a58fa2e4f779fe007820220215134918/b9fd46 there is a link to download my project so you can check, because i don't know how to do it

Comment: @StefanItic look at [what is a debugger and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @TalAngel ((RemoteWebElement)element).id = Cannot find local variable 'element' ----
this is what debbuger say

Comment: @StefanItic Please update your answer. Post the actual code you are using.

Comment: I debbuged, element is still null. It won't go inside if block and it doesn't click on anything... Maybe it's a problem because element i'm searching for is in on hover dropdown, and when i hover it new class appears "active". I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: @StefanItic LOL. Post a new question and tell us everything. If the element appears only after your hover - you have to wait after you hover. Read about webDriverWait.

Comment: Posted new one.