# Selenium test passes on hovering drop-down menu item click but does nothing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, mousehover

The website is https://cloudwise.nl/ I'm trying to click on Dit is Cloudwise > Alle Cludwisers with Selenium using Java. It's a hoverable drop-down menu so I saw people handle this situation with the help of waiting until the presence of Element Located functions. so that's my code piece:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        WebElement menu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul'][contains(text(),'Dit is Cloudwise')]"))));
        WebElement submenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-6380']//a[contains(text(),'Alle Cloudwisers')]")));
        action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-6380']//a[contains(text(),'Alle Cloudwisers')]"))).click().build().perform();
```

But the test still passes and it does not click. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261894/7429447) on *`Dit is Cloudwise`* and then to [*click*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on *`Alle Cludwisers`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='Dit is Cloudwise']")))).build().perform();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Dit is Cloudwise']//following::ul[1]/li/a"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Still got the same error: 

`Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //a[text()='Alle Cloudwisers']//following::ul[1]/li/a (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`

Comment: Can we use `visibilityOfElementLocated.build().perform()` at any hoverable object? Like even at buttons need hovering to become active?

Comment: Yes, but take care of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `presenceOfElementLocated` with `visibilityOfElementLocated`.
Also, looks like

```java
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-6380']//a[contains(text(),'Alle Cloudwisers')]"))).click().build().perform();
```

Can be changed with

```java
action.moveToElement(menu).moveToElement(submenu).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: I did the changes you mentioned but still doesn't work. Now I get the error:

`Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //a[@class='sf-with-ul'][contains(text(),'Dit is Cloudwise')] (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`

Comment: Is the submenu opens by hovering over the menu element or user need to click on menu to open the submenu?

Comment: Opens by hovering. These canges solved the problem:
 
`new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul'][contains(text(),'Dit is Cloudwise')]")))).build().perform();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-6380']//a[contains(text(),'Alle Cloudwisers')]"))).click();`

Answer (score 0):

@Erthan Yumer, you can achieve this in the way your initial implementation with the slight change as given below:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
WebElement menu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
        .presenceOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul'][contains(text(),'Dit is Cloudwise')]"))));
action.moveToElement(menu)
        .moveToElement(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-6380']//a[contains(text(),'Alle Cloudwisers')]"))))
        .click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but using visibilityOfElementLocated method solved my problem. And this is the code piece I used: 


`new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@class='sf-with-ul'][contains(text(),'Dit is Cloudwise')]")))).build().perform();


new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@id='menu-item-6380']//a[contains(text(),'Alle Cloudwisers')]"))).click();`