# Selenium Webriver:- How to click on this link?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, action

[image]

I have to take cursor on "Tickets" link and then click on the "Statuses".
As soon as i take cursor outside this window/frame this screen gets closes and i again have to take cursor on "Tickets" link.

HTML is:-
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't find the element with text as **Tickets** in the spashot. Additionally, please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: added the html for "tickets"

Answer (score 0):

To [***Mouse Hover***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47261894/7429447) over the element with text as ***Tickets*** and then to click on the element with text as ***Statuses*** you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
WebElement tickets = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@title='Tickets']")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(tickets).build().perform();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Statuses"))).click();
```

Optimizing the code you can use:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@title='Tickets']")))).build().perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='ember-view' and text()='Statuses']"))).click();
```

Comment: i am getting an error:-
java: incompatible types: java.time.Duration cannot be converted to long

Comment: Nopes, why would you convert it to `Duration.ofLong()`? Not needed really, use as it is `Duration.ofSeconds(5)`. Seems your framework issue.