# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element error while locating an element on a page using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape the text `睡觉` within the page `edited out the site`

It has the css selector:

```
#autocplt_wrap > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)
```

And x-Path:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul[1]/li/span/a[1]
```

My code is:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
//load webdriver
driver.Manage();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/#/cnen/home");
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ac_input")).SendKeys("睡觉" + Keys.Enter);
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#autocplt_wrap > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)"));
```

No matter what I try I always get the error:

```
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #autocplt_wrap > ul:nth-child(1) > 
li:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<CssSelector>b__0(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to extract the text **睡觉** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementIsVisible()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("a.srchword[data-entryid]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[@class='srchword' and @data-entryid]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

---

### Using `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` with `nuget`

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("a.srchword[data-entryid]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[@class='srchword' and @data-entryid]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [WebDriverWait is not waiting for the element I specify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488)

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on *NoSuchElementException* in:

- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471321/nosuchelementexception-selenium-unable-to-locate-element/48472940#48472940)
- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: hey, thanks a lot. this did the trick... with one exception. `ExpectedConditions` is depreciated now. You need to write your own function or install `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` with nuget

Comment: ooh forgot to mention you need to do that whole namespace thing. `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions` in case someone reads this in the future

Comment: @sourlemonaid Updated the answer with `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers`