# How to locate the element inside li tag using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

In my application, I want to assert a webelement name which is inside li tag. But I am unable to locate the same.

Below is the image of HTML code.I am unable to copy paste the code hence attaching the image.

[image]

The code which i tried is:

```
IWebElement result = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id='licredit-ResultDisplay']/a/b"));
Assert.AreEqual(result.Text, "ESTIMATE RESULTS");
Console.WriteLine("Estimate Result validated successfully");
```

But i am getting no such element error.So kindly suggest any suitable way to locate the element to assert the name-ESTIMATE RESULTS.

Answer (score 0):

your code may try to find the element before it exists, so my suggestion is use wait method. In Python it is something like :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:PATHchromedriver.exe');
driver.get("https://chercher.tech/practice/explicit-wait-sample-selenium-webdriver");
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30 /*timeout in seconds*/);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn1']"))));
```

But I don't know how to use it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are losing some character inside the Xpath.
This works for me:

> '//*[@id="licredit-ResultDisplay"]/a/b'

Since you are not looking for a tag "li" but an element by "id"

I hope it can work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of [OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104113/openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-error-while-loc/62108981#62108981) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementIsVisible()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement result = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("li#licredit-ResultDisplay>a>b")));
  Assert.AreEqual(result.Text, "ESTIMATE RESULTS");
  Console.WriteLine("Estimate Result validated successfully");
  ```
- Using `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement result = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//li[@id='licredit-ResultDisplay']/a/b")));
  Assert.AreEqual(result.Text, "ESTIMATE RESULTS");
  Console.WriteLine("Estimate Result validated successfully");
  ```