# Print text of elements from an list in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have to print all the text of the web elements, so i am storing the web elements in list "test" and then getting text of each web element and keep them adding to other list "Title".
Now when i am trying to print all the elements of list "Title".But only the text of 1st element is printed.
Please help me to find where i am going wrong.

```
public void PrintText() 
{            
    var Title = new List<string>();
    IList <IWebElement> test=Controls.GetWebElementList(X-path);

    foreach (var g in test)
    {
        Title.Add(Controls.GetText(x-path));           
    }

    foreach (var h in Title)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(h);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is length of List Title? I believe it is 1. Because there is no problem in printing the list logic. Your first foreach loop is iterating only for the one time

Comment: How is `Controls.GetWebElementList()` defined?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear how `Controls.GetWebElementList()` is defined.

Ideally to extract the texts you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for  `VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
IList <IWebElement> test = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("X-path")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.

Try to verify the first list to print their values.
[image]

And then run again, maybe your first line had only one value.

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much... My problem is solved now :)                     I had just made this change Title.Add(g.Text);           Thanks for the Help