# How to execute executeScript method through Java in Microsoft Edge through WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, execute-script

I am trying to run below code in Microsoft Edge through WebDriver

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return 
document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
boolean jsReady = (Boolean) js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
```

We are getting  below exception:

```
Exception class:org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException
```

The reason is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Function is not a constructor
```

We set EdgeOptions like below

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("MicrosoftEdge");
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);
edgeOptions.setCapability("prefs", edgePrefs);
edgeOptions.setCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
edgeOptions.merge(desiredCapabilities);
edgeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy("eager");
edgeOptions.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);
edgeOptions.setCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true);
driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
```

Any suggestions

Comment: Why are you calling the `getDriver` function I think you can write it as:
`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;`

Comment: Also I checked `return document.readyState`, it is returning null where as if I run similar command in browser console, it works fine. I rechecked and then it started to return a string instead of boolean value. So I suggest you should put a thread wait or a timer, for 3/4 seconds before running that command, then it will return you the string 'complete'

Comment: @UsmanWaheed public WebDriver getDriver(){
  return this.driver;
 } it will return driver

Comment: You wouldn't get that error from this, something else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

### [*executeScript()*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)

> Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or
> window. The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of
> an anonymous function. Within the script, use document to refer to the
> current document. Note that local variables will not be available once
> the script has finished executing, though global variables will
> persist. If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains
> a return statement), then the following steps will be taken:
>
> - For an HTML element, this method returns a WebElement
> - For a decimal, a Double is returned
> - For a non-decimal number, a Long is returned
> - For a boolean, a Boolean is returned
> - For all other cases, a String is returned.
> - For an array, return a List with each object following the rules above. We support nested lists.
> - For a map, return a Map<String, Object> with values following the rules above.
> - Unless the value is null or there is no return value, in which null is returned
>
> Arguments must be a number, a boolean, a String, WebElement, or a List
> of any combination of the above. An exception will be thrown if the
> arguments do not meet these criteria. The arguments will be made
> available to the JavaScript via the "arguments" magic variable, as if
> the function were called via "Function.apply"

---

### This usecase

If your usecase is to wait for *`document.readyState`* to be equal to ***`complete`*** you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(d => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
```