# Getting a value of ko.toJS using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, knockout.js

I'm trying to get values of input element which generated with ko.toJS using Selenium in Firefox:

```
<input autocomplete="on" class="form-control input-block-level " data-bind="value: $data.Reciever().LastName , disable: !$root.Actions.AllowChange()" data-code-in="false" data-fildid="945" data-param-getall="False" data-povalue="true" id="Reciever_LastName" name="Reciever.LastName" type="text" value="" disabled="" required="">...
```

JS code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
            window.DocMVVM = new UMT_Payout_MoneyMVVM(ko.toJS(
{"Sender":{"LastName":"ABC","FirstName":"BCA","Patronymic":"DEF"},
"Reciever":{"LastName":"GHI","FirstName":"IHG","Patronymic":"JKL"},...
```

I tried by CssSelector

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.form-control.input-block-level[id='Reciever_LastName']")).GetAttribute("value")
```

but the result is NULL.

Is anybody had such kind of task and how could I get values of inputs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the *`value`* attribute from the `<input>` element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the `ElementIsVisible()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.form-control.input-block-level#Reciever_LastName[name='Reciever.LastName']"))).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='form-control input-block-level ' and @id='Reciever_LastName'][@name='Reciever.LastName']"))).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```

Comment: I tried. The result is Null. Any other ideas?