# How to mouse hover multiple elements using Selenium and extract the texts through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, mousehover

I am currently trying to scrape a dynamic website which uses javascript to provide information after hovering over images. I am trying to obtain the data inside of the text containers brought up by hovering over these images, but am having difficulty doing so because when I define all of the elements, then attempt to create a loop which hovers over all of them, I only receive the text data from the first element I defined, over and over as many elements as there are (10 on this page.) Here is some code which should help you reproduce my problem. Do I need to induce waits into this loop in order to generate the proper results? Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Hank\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Unusual%20Old%20Guadalajara')
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
action = ActionChains(driver)
imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class^=market_listing_item_img][id^=listing_]')
for item in imgs:
    action.move_to_element(img).perform()
    descriptors = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'item_desc_descriptors')
    print(descriptors.text)
```

The code then proceeds to return exactly what I want for the FIRST element only. Thank you for your time, please let me know if there is an answer to my question somewhere else on the site, I've looked and can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To [mouse-hover](/questions/tagged/mouse-hover) over multiple elements using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Unusual%20Old%20Guadalajara')
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.market_listing_item_img.economy_item_hoverable")))
  for element in elements:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
      print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item_desc_description div.item_desc_descriptors#hover_item_descriptors div.descriptor")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='market_listing_item_img economy_item_hoverable']")))
  for element in elements:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
      print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item_desc_description']//div[@class='item_desc_descriptors' and @id='hover_item_descriptors']//div[@class='descriptor']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Paint Color: A Distinctive Lack of Hue', '★ Unusual Effect: Dead Presidents', "''It was opened with (Crate Depression 2019) as the first''"]
  ["★ Unusual Effect: Nuts n' Bolts", 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.']
  ['★ Unusual Effect: Orbiting Fire', 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.', 'Tradable After: Friday, June 19, 2020 (7:00:00) GMT']
  ['★ Unusual Effect: Bubbling', 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.', 'Gift from: Tombusken', 'Date Received: Sunday, December 22, 2013 (22:07:14) GMT']
  ['★ Unusual Effect: Orbiting Planets', 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.']
  ['Paint Color: Pink as Hell', '★ Unusual Effect: Purple Confetti', "''ABUELO! [8 bit fiesta music] PIEDRAS DE PERDENAL?''"]
  ['★ Unusual Effect: Cloud 9', 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.']
  ['★ Unusual Effect: Orbiting Planets', 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.']
  ['Paint Color: Pink as Hell', "★ Unusual Effect: Nuts n' Bolts", 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.']
  ['★ Unusual Effect: Molten Mallard', 'This hat adds spice to any occasion.']
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Scrape website with dynamic mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003)