# How to Mouse Hover multiple elements one by one and then click on an element within OrangeHRM website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, webdriverwait

On website https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/ I am trying to open the Admin box then the UserManagment and then click on Users. I do not understand where is my mistake. It gives me error AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement. I have read other related questions like mine but still I can't get the job done.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_id("txtUsername").send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element_by_id("txtPassword").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLogin").click()

admin=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewAdminModule']/b")
userManagment=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_UserManagement']")
users=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu_admin_viewSystemUsers']")
time.sleep(1)


actions=ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(admin).move_to_element(userManagment).move_to_element(users).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To login within *OrangeHRM*, [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003) on *Admin* then [*Mouse Hover*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376755/how-to-mouse-hover-multiple-elements-using-selenium-and-extract-the-texts-throug/62378044#62378044) on *User Management* and finally to [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on *Users* you you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#txtUsername"))).send_keys("Admin")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "txtPassword").send_keys("admin123")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "btnLogin").click()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#menu_admin_viewAdminModule")))).perform()
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#menu_admin_UserManagement")))).perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#menu_admin_viewSystemUsers"))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: OrangeHRM_Login_UserManagement_Users]