# Selenium Python: The second loop in the program isn't geting executed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

my code not working when reaching the second loop. when I hover over the first category it's showing the second category and I need to hover the second category to see the third category. here is my code:

```
driver.get("https://www.daraz.com.bd/")
main_category = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.lzd-site-menu-root-item span')
for i in main_category:
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(1) 
    sub_category_one = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR , ".Level_1_Category_No1 [data-spm-anchor-id] span")
    for i in sub_category_one:
             hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i)
             hover.perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903003/7429447) over the first category which shows the second categories and then to [Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62378044/7429447) over the second categories to see the third categories you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.daraz.com.bd/')
  main_category = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lzd-site-menu-root-item span")))
  for i in main_category:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(i).perform()
      time.sleep(1) 
      sub_category_one = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.Level_1_Category_No1 li.lzd-site-menu-sub-item")))
      for j in sub_category_one:
          ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(j).perform()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

First of to scrape the site, bs4 and iterating over the lists seems like a much better approach.

Now `find_elements` returns a list. You are iterating over a list with only one value in your second for loop. When I inspected the page I noticed that a submenu or subsubmenu that is active is assigned the class `lzd-site-menu-sub-active` and `lzd-site-menu-grand-active`.

```
main_category = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lzd-site-menu-root-item span")
for main in main_category:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(main).perform()

    sub_category = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
        lambda x: x.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lzd-site-menu-sub-item span")
    )
    for sub in sub_category:
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sub).perform()

        subsub_category = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
            lambda x: x.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lzd-site-menu-grand-item span")
        )

        for subsub in subsub_category:
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(subsub).perform()
```

This code manages to go hover over the third level as you will see. However because of the bad CSS_Selector it's somewhat useless.
I hope this could be of help.