# Getting wrong text value when using Xpath locator

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, getattribute

I'm currently learning Selenium and was given an test case to create, using **store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=topsellers** as an test site.
I need to get number that is near checkbox "Action", as [highlighted on a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn3PH.png)

This is a part of a page code that describes this specific checkbox:

```
<div class="tab_filter_control_row " data-param="tags" data-value="19" data-loc="Action" data-clientside="0">
    <span class="tab_filter_control tab_filter_control_include " data-param="tags" data-value="19" data-loc="Action" data-clientside="0" data-gpfocus="item">
        <span>
                <span class="tab_filter_control_checkbox"></span>
                <span class="tab_filter_control_label">Action</span>
                <span class="tab_filter_control_count" style="">30</span>
        </span>
    </span>
                <span class="tab_filter_control_not " data-param="untags" data-value="19" data-icon="https://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/search_crouton_not.svg" data-loc="Action" data-clientside="0" data-tooltip-text="Exclude results with this tag" data-gpfocus="item"><img src="https://store.akamai.steamstatic.com/public/images/search_checkbox_not.svg" width="16px" height="16px"></span>
        </div>
```

To do that I wrote this XPath locator: **//span[@data-value='19']//*[@class='tab_filter_control_count']**. But when I do something like this:

```
string str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-value='19']//*[@class='tab_filter_control_count']"));
```

I for some reason will get "1 635", not "30". I tried to get text by using different XPath, **//div[@data-collapse-name='tags']//*[@data-value='19']**, but result will be "Action 1 635".

Maybe somebody will explain how 30 turns into 1 635 and how I can get the right number.

Comment: You know that steam offers an API? https://steamcommunity.com/dev - seems easier than trying to parse the HTML.

Comment: I am limited by the requirement of the test case to only use a specific programming language, IDE, etc. I will look into this, but I'm sure there is an easier solution for this small part of the entire test case than using the new API.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text *`30`* next to the label *Action* you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *Text* attribute:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Action']//following::span[1]")).Text);
  ```

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired *ElementIsVisible* and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and `GetAttribute()`:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//span[text()='Action']//following::span[1]"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```