# How to hover over an item avoiding a click on it using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, hover, mousehover

I have a problem, I want to hover over a certain button (to develop) but I don't want to click it, I don't know how to do it. when I click this button, it takes me to another place and I don't want it

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = textBox1.Text;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); Thread.Sleep(2000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(3000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space()='Mój OLX']")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(2000); 

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//section[@class='login-page has-animation']//input[@id='userEmail']")).SendKeys("anastazja.bendkowska@wp.pl"); Thread.Sleep(3000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='userPass']")).SendKeys("Anastazja12345");

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//section[@class='login-page has-animation']//button[@id='se_userLogin']")).Click(); Thread.Sleep(3000);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='css-1povu0j']"));


            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space()='Wyloguj']")).Click();
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("")).Click();


        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a mouse over using selenium webdriver to see the hidden menu without performing any mouse clicks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355515/how-to-do-a-mouse-over-using-selenium-webdriver-to-see-the-hidden-menu-without-p)

Comment: not so much, I want to hover over an element without clicking on it and this post is about something else

Comment: The mentioned "action.MoveToElement" method in @gunr2171 link seems spot on to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hover over a certain button but to avoid clicking it you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554298/webdriverwait-is-not-waiting-for-the-element-i-specify/57554488#57554488) for the desired [`ElementIsVisible()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69946795/getting-wrong-text-value-when-using-xpath-locator/69949598#69949598) and the use [Actions Class](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) methods as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[normalize-space()='Wyloguj']")));

Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Scrape website with dynamic mouseover event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003)
- [How to mouse hover using java through selenium-webdriver and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261078/how-to-mouse-hover-using-java-through-selenium-webdriver-and-java/47261894#47261894)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Action` after you find the element you want to hover

```
    var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='css-1povu0j']"));
    Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
    action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
```